# Generic implicit cast of Func<T, T> to T

Tags: c#, generics

So I have this snippet of code, inspired by javascript's self initializing anonymous functions.

```
public static Contact Login(string username, string passwordHash = null)
{
    return ((Func<Contact, Contact>)(c => {
            if (c != null) {
                var context = new CurrentContext();
                context.Contact = c;
                context.Save();
            }
            return c;
        }))(GetContactFromDatabase(username) ?? GetContactFromWebService(username, passwordHash));
}
```

It works great, but the **Func Contact, Contact** is a little to verbose for my liking.
I would like the compiler to work out the casting by the argument types passed in at the end.

Something like this:

```
public class AF<T>
{
    public static implicit operator T(Func<T, T> fun)
    {
        return fun();
    }
}
```

But it won't compile. I have in mind a class not unlike the c# tuple class, that defines itself with something like 15 different T's.

The end code would look something like:

```
public static Contact Login(string username, string passwordHash = null)
{
    return ((AF)(c => {
            if (c != null) {
                var context = new CurrentContext();
                context.Contact = c;
                context.Save();
            }
            return c;
        }))(GetContactFromDatabase(username) ?? GetContactFromWebService(username, passwordHash));
}
```

Maybe there is a clever extension method that can accomplish this syntax sugar?

I ended up using the follow in a class without a namespace:

```
public delegate T F<T>(T value);

public static class GenericExtensions {
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static T For<T>(this F<T> function, T value) {
        return function(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? The question is why to do it? Wouldn't it look much more readable  if you extract the anonymous code block to the separate function? Excuse me, but I don't see any "sugar" in the second code block as well. Syntax sugar usually means some elegant piece of code, but the above one is not the case

Comment: The `Login` method would be much more readable (and actually less verbose) if you avoided a lambda expression altogether and just wrote it in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish your intent if you do not use Anonymous functions but delegates otherwise

```
public delegate int Contacts(int a, int b);

    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static void Test()
        {            
            Contacts contactsFunc = (Contacts)((a, b) => a + b);
            contactsFunc(2, 3);
            //less verbose mode
            ((Contacts)((a, b) => a + b))(2,3);
        }
    }
```

but i have to agree with **wdosanjos** and tell you to not use lambdas.

*Side note: Mapping Javascript programming style to c# might not be the best guide (disclaimer: but i am no big fan of Javascript)*

Answer (score 7):

Just make it simple and avoid the lambda:

```
public static Contact Login(string username, string passwordHash = null)
{
    Contact c = GetContactFromDatabase(username) ?? GetContactFromWebService(username, passwordHash);

    if (c != null) {
       var context = new CurrentContext();
       context.Contact = c;
       context.Save();
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Why are you saying not to use a lambda? What is wrong with the pattern?

Comment: Using a lambda makes this code more complicated.  Simpler is better.  Lambdas have some benefits as type safe abstractions of method references, but there is no need for indirection here.